# How to import ICEDIS file format into sql server database with asp.net file upload

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2014

I need to be able to load the ICEDIS file format into sql server database. User should be able to have the ability to "Select file to upload" using file upload control. Then select the file and upload into system. Then integrate into system.
Give me Example or hint.

Comment: Please find below link, it might help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231414/how-to-load-a-flat-file-with-header-and-detail-data-into-a-database-using-ssis-p

Comment: Please find below link, it might help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231414/how-to-load-a-flat-file-with-header-and-detail-data-into-a-database-using-ssis-p